# Translating IMAP body based on their encoding

Tags: php, encoding, imap, decoding

From the manual, I know that there are [6 different transfer encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) in IMAP.

At this point, I've created this basic function:

```
function translate_imap_body($body, $encoding) {
    switch($encoding) {
        case 0: return $body;break;
        case 1: return $body;break;
        case 2: return $body;break;
        case 3: return base64_decode($body);break;
        case 4: return quoted_printable_decode($body);break;
        case 5: return $body;break;
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I translate 8bit, binary, and other encoding back to human readable message form? Or, maybe someone has better functions to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To translate your 8 bit binary to human readable, try this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php

Comment: oops, asked the question too fast. A little bit searching got me this URL: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php#43405